# How to install ubuntu(*.iso) remotely in a machine currently running an ubuntu already?

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, iso

I just want to virtualize an old system environment to test whether my software can work or not.

I have an ISO link: https://nigos.nist.gov/evaluations/ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso

And I can access a remote Ubuntu machine using SSH.

Here are more details for the current running one:

```
$ uname -a
Linux intern 6.2.0-36-generic #37~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct 9 15:34:04 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Is there any method that I can remotely download a `.iso` file on the machine and install Ubuntu of that version in that machine remotely rather than using CD/DVD?

It would be better if someone could provide a solution and steps.

Comment: You can remotely upgrade the version of Ubuntu (this is a non-reversible process) but I don't think you can install Ubuntu without physical access to the machine.

Comment: Got it thank you for letting me know

Answer (score 1):

"*Is there any method that I can remotely download .iso file on the machine and install ubuntu of that version in that machine remotely rather than using CD/DVD?*"

No.

Installing any computer operating system, including Ubuntu, onto a physical machine requires access to the hardware.

Try for yourself: Take two laptops, set them side by side, and try to use Laptop A to remotely install a new OS onto Laptop B. You will encounter several brick walls: The remote control software won't run under the installer. The network connection will be reset in the middle of the install process. You cannot change BIOS options. The installer recognizes only the real hardware screen and won't feed that image elsewhere. Lots more.

You can remotely install Virtual Machines because you're really just talking to the Host VM application.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, 
I recently find How to boot virtual machines using ISO file on
https://www.manageengine.com/products/os-deployer/help/boot-computers-using-iso.html
But I am not sure
In this way, whether combined with a remote controlled software to the remote computer, will work or not?

Comment: Thank you for your in details and reliable explaination and helps， I will install iso using usb driver in person